# adding a layer to a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a global dictionary like the following in my code:

```
param_values = {
            'aa' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),   (-1,-1)],     
            'ae' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (0.1,0.8), (-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'ah' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'ao' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.2,1.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'b'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.0,0.0),  (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'ch' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            'd'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            'dh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.35),  (-1,-1)], 
            'dx' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.35),  (-1,-1)], 
            'eh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'er' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.15,0.7),  (-1,-1)], 
            'ey' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (0.3,1.0), (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.5),   (-1,-1)], 
            'f'  : [(0.3,1.0), (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (-1,-1)], 
            'g'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'hh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'ih' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'iy' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (0.2,1.0), (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'jh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'k'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'l'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            'm'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.0,0.0),  (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'n'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),  (-1,-1),   (0.3,1.0), (0.0,0.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'ng' : [(-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),  (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.0,0.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'p'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.0,0.0),  (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'r'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            's'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),  (-1,-1),   (0.3,1.0), (0.0,0.0),   (-1,-1)],
            'sh' : [(-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),  (-1,-1),   (0.3,1.0), (0.0,0.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            't'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            'th' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            'uh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (0.1,1.0)], 
            'uw' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (0.1,1.0)], 
            'v'  : [(0.3,1.0), (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (-1,-1)], 
            'w'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (0.1,1.0)], 
            'y'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.6),   (-1,-1)],  
            'z'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),  (-1,-1),   (0.3,1.0), (0.0,0.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'zh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.6),   (-1,-1)], 
            'o'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (0.4,1.0)]
            }
```

But I have to add in a layer and separate into vowels and consonants, something like the following.

```
param_values = {
            'vowels':{
            'aa' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),   (-1,-1)],     
            'ae' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (0.1,0.8), (-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'ah' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'ao' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.2,1.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'eh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'er' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.15,0.7),  (-1,-1)], 
            'ey' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (0.3,1.0), (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.5),   (-1,-1)],
            'ih' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'iy' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (0.2,1.0), (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'uh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (0.1,1.0)], 
            'uw' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (0.1,1.0)],   
            'o'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (0.4,1.0)]    
            },
            'consonants':{
            'b'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.0,0.0),  (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'ch' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            'd'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            'dh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.35),  (-1,-1)], 
            'dx' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.35),  (-1,-1)], 
            'f'  : [(0.3,1.0), (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (-1,-1)], 
            'g'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'hh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'jh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'k'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'l'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            'm'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.0,0.0),  (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'n'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),  (-1,-1),   (0.3,1.0), (0.0,0.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'ng' : [(-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),  (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.0,0.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'p'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.0,0.0),  (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'r'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            's'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),  (-1,-1),   (0.3,1.0), (0.0,0.0),   (-1,-1)],
            'sh' : [(-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),  (-1,-1),   (0.3,1.0), (0.0,0.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            't'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            'th' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            'v'  : [(0.3,1.0), (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (-1,-1)], 
            'w'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (0.1,1.0)], 
            'y'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.6),   (-1,-1)],  
            'z'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),  (-1,-1),   (0.3,1.0), (0.0,0.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'zh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.6),   (-1,-1)] 
             }                         
            }
```

This is now correct as my question has been edited. Thank you.

Comment: OK, and what's your question?

Comment: and I want money for doing your homework. Please tell us what you've tried to do, where you have problems, etc... oh and of course that's a dictionary, not a list.

Comment: And your "result" isn't valid Python.

Comment: @zingy: What Tim means is that the values of your final param_values dictionary should be dictionaries (like your initial param_values).  You used the list notation [] instead of {}.

Comment: Lists are of the form [1, 2, 3, ...]
Dictionaries are of the form {'a':1, 'b':2, ...}
You're mixing them by writing {'vowels': ['aa':[], ... ] ...
That should be {'vowels': {'aa':[], ...}, ...

Comment: @jcfollower Thank you for the correction. Indeed it is a dictionary but I am habituated with lists so made a mistake.

Comment: @Frank Sorry this is not a homework but a research and I am a beginner in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to go through your initial dictionary only once, you can do:

```
vowels, consonants = {}, {}
for (letters, data) in param_values.iteritems():
    relevant_dict = vowels if is_vowel(letters) else consonants
    relevant_dict[letters] = data
param_values = {'vowels': vowels, 'consonants': consonants}
```

This solution has the advantage of explicitly showing in a single line that letters go either in `vowels` or in `consonants`.

Comment: It seems to be constant-size, though, so there's no need for a more complicated one-pass algorithm.

Comment: @larsmans: What do you mean by "constant-size"?  that the size of the input is known in advance, and is quite small?  In any case, I did not downvote your answer, which I find to be quite valid for the case at hand, even though it is not the solution I would use for larger inputs. :)

Comment: The human voice can produce (or perhaps, linguists can recognize) only a small number of vowels and consonants, so there's a small upper limit to the number of items to be scanned. I don't object to your solution, it's just slightly longer than mine (though less repetitive).

Comment: Thanks.  I see.  Yeah, your solution has the advantage of being shorter, and, again, fine for the case at hand.

Answer (score 2):

```
vowels = [(k, v) for k, v in param_values.iteritems() if is_vowel(k)]
consonants = [(k, v) for k, v in param_values.iteritems() if not is_vowel(k)]
param_values = {'vowels': vowels, 'consonants': consonants}
```

Comment: This goes through the `param_values` dictionary twice, which is fine here because it's a small dictionary, but a more general solution goes through the dictionary only once, because it should be faster.

Comment: True, but this is more readable. +1 to your solution. I like your if-then-else expression.